# how to embed a button in a textbox control using c# in compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, controls

I'm trying to create a searchbox control using c# in compact framework. I'm thinking of developing a custom control which has a textbox with a button at the end of it. This button should be overlayed with a picture (of a magnifying glass to indicate search action). It should ideally look like the google search toolbar control.

Is this doable? How should I start? Any pointers or code examples would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not just create a custom control, consisting of a textbox and a button just to the right of the textbox? You could then add a border / styling to it to make them look as if its a single control.

Shouldn't be too difficult